# Google Analytics onClick goal(event) tracking not working

Tags: google-analytics

Here's an image of the settings I have in the admin panel.
[image: Settings]

And here's the code on the button, which is a form submit button.

```
<input type="submit" id="so-submitso1519662919 so-submit" class="so-submit-class" value="Check" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'buttons', 'click', 'Split Test A');">
```

I'm loading Analytics through Google Tag Manger.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

The script for my analytics was using GTAG so the code needed to be gtag();.